# heroku run rake db:migrate error “/usr/bin/env: ruby2.2: No such file or directory”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

I'm brand new to Rails and I'm following this tutorial. I successfully pushed my app to heroku, but I can't get the database migrate.

I use a virtual machine with ubuntu server .

I typed:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and got this error:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3356
/usr/bin/env: ruby2.2: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand what I can do. I tried to use

```
$ heroku run rails db:migrate
$ rake rails:update:bin
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: What version of Rails does your application run on? And what tutorial are you following?

Comment: @vape Thanks for your advice, but it didn't help. I resieved the same error. I used to Rails 4.2.0. And the tutorial I'm following is https://www.railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the solution that worked for me is that for every file in the `bin` directory of my project, i changed the first line from:

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby2.2`

to

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`